# hiding and showing images with setVisible method

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I wrote a class that uses buttons to play radio stations broadcast to the internet.
When the buttons are pressed, I also wanted to have a series of images in the Frame selectively hidden and shown.

I am trying to do this by adding Images, setting "setVisible(false);" and then overriding the setVisible method when the button is clicked.
It isn't viable in it's current state. Is there a way to do this?

I'm pretty new to writing code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
  String  text   = button.getText();

  JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("resources/1920.png"));
  img.setBounds(642, 230, 100, 100); // x, y, width, height
  add(img);
  img.setVisible(false);

  if (text.equals("1920a"))
  {
     try
     {
       getMediaPlayer().setURI(mediaPaths[0]); 
       img.setVisible(true);

     }
     catch (URISyntaxException e1)
     {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: why do u create jlales inside of actionPerformed event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you press the button, you are creating a new instance of a `JLabel` and adding it to the screen, but you're not keeping track of them...

```
// Yet ANOTHER label...which one it is, nobody knows...
JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("resources/1920.png"));
img.setBounds(642, 230, 100, 100); // x, y, width, height
add(img);
img.setVisible(false);
```

If you only want a single image on the screen at a time, then simply change the icon label of a single label...

Start by declaring an instance field for the pictures...

```
public class ... {
    //...
    private JLabel pictureLabel;
```

Add the label to the screen...

```
public ... { // Public constructor
    //...
    pictureLabel = new JLabel();
    add(pictureLabel);
```

Now, when you want to change the picture, simply change the icon property of the label...

```
pictureLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/1920.png"));
```